# Everything but 'property' greyed out in calculate geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

[image: coordinate system and units both greyed out in calculate geometry]

In calculate geometry, I need to change the units to square metres, however all but 'property' is greyed out. (See image)

I have tried this with editing on and off, same result.

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Your data has no coordinate system projection (Unknown), so it cannot determine what units of measure the data is based on, and therefore cannot convert to another unit of measure.  You need to assign the coordinate system the data was based on to the shapefile first.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the coordinate system in your feature class of shapefile.

If you know the coordinate system, you should use "define projection (data management)" then you can calculate the Geometry.